# How can i construct a vector space with exactly 9 elements?

Tags: vector-spaces

Do i need to pick two vectors from the vector space, say x = { nine elements} and y = { nine elements} that contains 9 elements each and then apply the 10 properties of a vector space on them.Sorry if my questions look wayward. Am new to math but i really wanna understand 
Thanks

Comment: Hint: Every field can be thought of a vector space over itself, do you know a field with exactly $9$ elements?

Comment: Have you already studied finite fields (and their extensions), rings of polynomials over them, quotient rings and etc.?

Comment: I think the OP might be meant to take a space of dimension 2 rather than 1 as they are more likely to have seen the ingredients for this.

Comment: You say you are new to math - but do you know anything about finite fields?

Comment: Actually we've just started an introductory course to linear algebra. So I know a vector space, field but not finite field, transformation,  basis and dimensions

Comment: If you don't know about finite fields, you can't do the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a field with exactly three elements. Let's call it $F$. Then $F^2$, the set of all ordered pairs of elements of $F$, is what you're looking for. Can you fill in the details?

Comment: And, let's face it, finding a field with $3$ elements is a lot easier than finding a field with $9$ elements.

Comment: Yup. One easy example of a construction of a field with $9$ elements is $$\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z[x]\;/\;\langle x^2+1\rangle$$Otherwise known as $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z[i]$.

Comment: @Don up to isomorphism that's *the only* field with nine elements.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Also, sorry for commenting on this old post. I didn't realize that the question was old (it showed up in review).

Comment: @Don it's always open season for comments, there's no statute of limitations.